# how to convert String date 2015-02-12 to 12-02-2015 in java

Tags: java

how to convert String date 2015-02-12 to 12-02-2015 in java 
i take date from one form by date picker and it results string date 
like 2014-02-19 but i want to display date in 19-02-2014

Comment: Please explore SimpleDateFormat
This is very simple in java.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `SimpleDateFormat`, and parse the given date to required format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat givenFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date givendate = givenFormat.parse("2015-02-12");
        SimpleDateFormat ouputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String newDate = ouputFormat.format(givendate);
        System.out.println(newDate);
    }
```

**output**

```
12-02-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
private static String tranPattern(String ori) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat ouputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    return ouputFormat.format(format.parse(ori));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the input string is fixed you could use the replaceAll method.

```
String in = "2015-02-12";
//                             +-- match four characters in group 1
//                             |     |+-- - match two characters in group 2
//                           vvvv   vv   vv-- - match two characters in group 3 
String out = in.replaceAll("(....)-(..)-(..)", "$3-$2-$1");
//                                              replace the input string by the 
//                                              matching groups
System.out.println("out = " + out);
```

If you are using the JavaFX DatePicker you might have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a split/reverse/join on the `-`:

```
package so28360178;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.reverse;
import static java.lang.String.format;

public class App {

    public static final Joiner JOINER = Joiner.on('-');
    public static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on('-');

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // with guava Splitter/Joiner and Lists#reverse
        System.out.println(JOINER.join(reverse(newArrayList(SPLITTER.split("2015-02-12"))))); // 12-02-2015

        // plain old java using String#format for the reverse
        System.out.println(format("%3$s-%2$s-%1$s", "2015-02-12".split("-"))); // 12-02-2015
    }
}
```